# There are many warnings in Location Routing Problem Model and how to add subtour elimination constraints?

Tags: routes, location, warnings, cplex

I get this 99 warnings:

> Decision variable "Q#0" has never been used by the engine".

What can be the reason behind this error? How can I solve it? If you can help me, I will be really glad.

Also, how to add the traditional subtour elimination constraints in this OPL? (I add `.mod` and `.data`)

I've tried some code for subtour elimination, but it didn't work:

```
tuple edge{
  int i;
  int j;
};
setof(edge) Edges = {<i,j>|ordered i,j in vertices};

range SubtourId = 1.. ftoi(pow(2,card(toko)));
{int} Subtours[s in SubtourId] = {i|i in toko: ((s div (ftoi(pow(2,(ord(asSet(toko),i))))) mod 2) == 1)};

//Subtour elimination        
 // ct05: forall(k in kendaraan,s in SubtourId:card(Subtours[s])>0)
// sum(i in Subtours[s],j in Subtours[s]) X[<i,j,k>] <= card(Subtours[s])-1; 



int d=...;
range depot=1..d;

int n=...;
range toko=d+1..d+n;
range vertices=1..d+n;

int v=...;
range kendaraan=1..v;

int eco2=...;

int q=...;
int capdep=...; //capacity depot
int M=...; //possible max item can be send from node i to node j

tuple Cij{
int i;
int j;
}

tuple xijk{
int i;
int j;
int k;
}

tuple Oi{
int i;
}

tuple Fij{
int i;
int j;
}


tuple Qijk{ 
int i;
int j;
int k;
}

tuple Yi{
int i;
}


tuple dj{
int j;
}

setof (dj) demandcust={<j> | j in toko};
setof (Oi) openedcost={<i> | i in depot};
setof (Fij) assigned={<i,j> | i,j in vertices: i!=j};
setof (Qijk) qdelivery={<i,j,k> |i,j in vertices: i!=j, k in kendaraan};
setof (Yi) dcopened={<i> | i in depot};
setof (xijk) route={<i,j,k> | i,j in vertices: i!=j, k in kendaraan};
setof (Cij) travelingcost={<i,j> | i,j in vertices: i!=j};

float opencost[openedcost]=...;
float matrikscost[travelingcost]=...;
float demand[demandcust]=...;

//decision variable
dvar boolean X[route]; // 1 if the arc (i,j) used in the route performed by the vehicle k, 0 otherwise.
dvar boolean Y[dcopened]; //1 if depot i ∈ I is opened and 0 otherwise
dvar int+ Q[qdelivery]; //Quantity delivered from depot i∈ I to customer j∈ J by vehicle k ∈ K
dvar boolean A[assigned];//1 if clients j is assigned to depot I and 0 otherwise (fij)

dexpr float depotestablish=sum(i in depot) opencost[<i>]*Y[<i>];
dexpr float travelcost=sum(i,j in vertices: i!=j, k in kendaraan) matrikscost[<i,j>]*X[<i,j,k>];
dexpr float emissionCost=sum(i,j in vertices: i!=j, k in kendaraan) matrikscost[<i,j>]*eco2*X[<i,j,k>];

//objective functions:
minimize (depotestablish+travelcost+emissionCost); 

subject to{
//the capacity constraints of vehicles
forall (k in kendaraan)
  constraint_2:
  sum(i in depot, j in toko) Q[<i,j,k>] == q; 

//vehicle flow conservation 
    forall (i in vertices, k in kendaraan)
      constraint_3:
     sum(j in vertices: j!=i) X[<i,j,k>] - sum (j in vertices: j!=i) X[<j,i,k>]==0 ;
    forall ( j in toko)
      constraint_4:
      sum (i in depot, k in kendaraan) X[<i,j,k>] <= 1;
    forall (j in toko)
      constraint_5:
      sum(i in depot, k in kendaraan) X[<j,i,k>]<= 1;

//forces each vehicle to perform 1 route/period at most
forall (k in kendaraan) 
constraint_6:
  sum (i in depot, j in toko) X[<i,j,k>]==1;

//each customer must be allocated to a single opened depot
forall (j in vertices)
  constraint_7:
  sum (i in vertices: i!=j) A[<i,j>] == 1;

//a retailer j can’t be linked to a depot i if j is not assigned to depot i  
forall (i in depot, j in toko, k in kendaraan)
  constraint_8:
  sum(a in toko)X[<i,a,k>]+ sum(a in depot)X[<a,j,k>]<=1+A[<i,j>];

//The capacity of each depot is
forall (i in depot)
  constraint_9:
  sum (j in toko, k in kendaraan) Q[<i,j,k>]<= Y[<i>]*capdep;

//the maximum number of customers per route
forall (k in kendaraan)
  constraint_12:
  sum(i,j in vertices: i!=j) X[<i,j,k>]<=3; 
//if a retailer is served with route k, it must be visited.
forall (i in depot, j in toko)
  constraint_14:
    sum (k in kendaraan) Q[<i,j,k>]<=M*A[<i,j>]; //diganti<

forall (i in depot, j in toko, k in kendaraan)
  constraint_15:
  Q[<i,j,k>]<=M*sum(u in toko)X[<i,u,k>];
}

Data:
n=8;
v=4;
d=3;
q=400;
M=400; 
eco2=1018;
capdep=1000;
opencost=[150000000, 150000000,  150000000];
matrikscost=[3  40  20  60  50  786 54  627 29  29
30      20  21  14  40  28  5   631 23  23
4   5       40  89  28  288 9   947 96  96
627 29  54      12  288 937 104 786 97  97
631 23  5   631     937 282 85  28  53  53
947 96  9   947 96      104 14  288 58  58
786 97  104 786 97  288     89  937 89  89
28  53  85  28  53  937 96      282 63  63
288 58  14  288 58  282 97  63      282 89
937 9   89  937 89  104 53  89  288     12
282 63  12  282 63  89  58  12  937 282];

demand=[280 320 320 400 350 400 290 380];
```

I don't know how to add the traditional subtour elimination constraints:

`sum (i in S, j in S) Xijk <= |S| -1 ∀S∈toko, ∀k∈vehicle`

Answer (score 0):

in the CPLEX product you may have a look at the example [tsp](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.1/ilog.odms.ide.help/examples/html/opl/models/TravelingSalesmanProblem/tsp.mod.html) which adds subtours incrementally.

Or you could write them with [MTZ or use CPO](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=f58daf79-f752-48e4-8f25-54b2f6f71b40&ps=25)

If you really want to remove all circuits you may try something like

```
 // Cities
int     n       = ...;
range   Cities  = 1..n;

// Edges -- sparse set
tuple       edge        {int i; int j;}
setof(edge) Edges       = {<i,j> | ordered i,j in Cities};
int         dist[Edges] = ...;

// Decision variables
dvar boolean x[Edges];

 {int} nodes={i.i | i in Edges} union {i.j | i in Edges};

range r=1..-2+ftoi(pow(2,card(nodes)));


{int} nodes2 [k in r] = {i | i in nodes: ((k div (ftoi(pow(2,(ord(nodes,i))))) mod 2) == 1)};





/*****************************************************************************
 *
 * MODEL
 *
 *****************************************************************************/

// Objective
minimize sum (<i,j> in Edges) dist[<i,j>]*x[<i,j>];
subject to {

   // Each city is linked with two other cities
   forall (j in Cities)
        sum (<i,j> in Edges) x[<i,j>] + sum (<j,k> in Edges) x[<j,k>] == 2;

   // Subtour elimination constraints.


forall(k in r)  // all subsets but empty and all
    sum(e in Edges:(e.i in nodes2[k]) && (e.j in nodes2[k])) x[e]<=card(nodes2[k])-1;  

 }
```

Comment: can you tell me what is the meaning of the decision variable x get 1 or 0? and how can I solve the 99 warnings? thank you..